# MS Access SELECT query not taking date format

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a query to find records with a certain date here:

```
select *
from data
where start_date = 7/12/2014
```

This returns one empty record.

The `start_date` field is of format "Date/Time" as seen in Design view. When in Table view, each date in that field is in the mm/dd/yyyy format.

I manually converted the date to days since 1900, as is used in Excel, and the query worked and returned what I needed, but I have many dates and don't want to do this for each one. I also tried things such as `'7/12/2014'` etc but to no avail.

Is there a way to be able to search with the current format (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Not sure if this has any effect, but when I populated the `start_date` field, all the dates were in days since 1900 format, and the data type auto-set to Number. I changed the data type to Date/Time in design view and when I went back in Table view, the values were in mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Try `07/12/2014`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose dates in `#` signs in Access SQL.
This should work:

```
select *
from data
where start_date = #7/12/2014#
```